# How to query and update entries in MongoDB (Pymongo) effectively?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a function where if I pass in an `MongoDB.Collection.Object`, it might or might not give me a vector `[1,2,3,4...]`. First of all, I need to extract all the required queries and then update the entries based on each. Problem is that I have this sort of function:

```
def return_vector(q):
  # condition = my_logic
  if condition:
    return vector
  else:
    return None'

for q in db.coll_name.find({'a.b.c':{'$gt':0.4}}):
  vector = return_vector(q)
  if q:
    db.coll_name.update({'_id': q['_id']},{'$set': {'vector_v1': vector}})
```

Problem? It is taking too much time. How am I supposed to do it with in optimized manner effectively?

Comment: Sorry that did not work for me. I had to ask for the Node guys to handle thing. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Np, Thanks for the reploy

Answer (score 1):

You do multiple updates. It could be one of the reason for slowness.

You can combine multiple updates and send one request rot he server using `bulkwrite`. It would significantly reduce network round trip time.

Hope you don't have multiple write requests for the same document at the same time.

Comment: Can you please write a dummy code to do that?  I think `find()` or `arrgegate` would be useful here. anyways, I'll have to write one by one in any case. I can't multiple write. Can I?

Comment: I am suggesting you `bulkWrite` as you need to update.